# Pig filter command is not work

Tags: java, apache-pig

I tried below in PIG but 4th command is not working.

```
A = load '/user/mziauddi/logsam.txt' AS (str:chararray);
split1 = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(str, '\\,', 2)) AS (id:chararray, attr:chararray);
split2 = FOREACH split1 GENERATE id, STRSPLIT(attr, '[,]') AS attributes;
ORDER = FILTER split2 BY id=='ORD';
```

Comment: How is this programming? I think this better fits something like SuperUser. At the very least, this is a debugging question, and not suited for this site. That ignores the fact that you are giving barely any information -- what do you mean by "[the command] is not working"? How is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER` is a built-in command in Pig, you should not use as a relation name. Can you change the relation name(`ORDER`) to something different.